# When is the Chern class of a principal $G$-bundle same to the Chern class of the associated complex vector bundle?

Tags: vector-bundles, fibre-bundles, principal-bundles, chern-classes, hopf-fibration

Let $P\rightarrow M$ be a principal bundle, with structure group $G$. If $G$ has a representation $\rho:G\rightarrow GL(n,\mathbb{C})$, then we can define its associated vector bundle $E=P\times_{\rho}\mathbb{C}^{n}$.

Since a connection $A$ on $P$ induces a covariant differential $\nabla$ on $E$, I would say that the Chern classes defined on $P$ is the same to the Chern classes defined on $E$.

***Is the above statement correct?***

I got confused because one can define the so-called adjoint bundle $ad(P)=P\times_{Ad}\mathfrak{g}$, where $Ad$ represents the adjoint action of $G$ acting on its own Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Such a bundle has typical fiber $\mathfrak{g}$ being the Lie algebra of its own structure group.

Take the canonical line bundle over $\mathbb{CP}^{1}$ as an example. The total space of the principal bundle is $S^{3}$, which is non-trivial. However, starting from the principal bundle $S^{3}\rightarrow\mathbb{CP}^{1}$, the adjoint bundle seems to be $\mathbb{CP}^{1}\times\mathbb{R}$, which is trivial, because its structure group $U(1)$ is abelian and the first Stiefel-Whitney class is zero.

Now, both the trivial line bundle and the canonical line bundle are the associated vector bundle of the same hopf fibration, but the adjoint bundle doesn't even have a Chern class.

***Is that really true that the Chern class $c_{i}(P)$ of a principal bundle is same to the Chern class $c_{i}(E)$ of its associated vector bundle $E$?***

***In general, under what situation will the Chern class of a principal $G$-bundle be same to the Chern class of any of associated complex vector bundle?***

Comment: I don't think there is a definition of the Chern classes $c_i(P)$ of a principal bundle. For instance, what are the allowed values of $i$?

Comment: Maybe the OP is asking about the comparison between the Chern classes of the rank-$n$ vector bundle associated to a principal $\text{GL}_n$-bundle and the rank-$n^2$ vector bundle that is the adjoint bundle of that principal bundle.

Comment: @Will Sawin Doesn't the expression $\mathrm{Det}(1+\frac{iF}{2\pi})$, where $F=dA+A\wedge A$ define the Chern class of the principal bundle with the connection $A$? I found physicists talking about this in some papers about Chern-Simons theory.

Comment: @NewStudent Determinant acting on what?

Comment: @Will Sawin https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-55084-8_6 It defines the Chern classes of a principal bundle.

Comment: @WillSawin It seems that the curvature form in both associated vector bundle and the principal bundle is the same. This makes me very confused because there can be trivial adjoint bundle.

Comment: The physicists were playing fast and lose: the definition of Chern class requires a determinant, as you have in your formula, so they are assuming that $G$ is a group of matrices, i.e. has a given faithful representation.

Comment: Thank you @BenMcKay. So I think the condition is that the representation must be faithful?

Comment: The Chern classes for a principal $U(n)$-bundle are, by definition, the Chern classes of the associated $\mathbb C^n$ bundle given by the standard $U(n)$-action on $\mathbb C^n$. The adjoint bundle isn't the right one to take and it has nothing to do with the matter.

Comment: Hi @IgorBelegradek, could you explain more about why adjoint bundle isn't the right one to take? I found from this book https://books.google.se/books?id=l6F0DgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false example 4.3.13 that the author is talking about the Chern class of the complexification of the adjoint bundle.

Comment: @NewStudent: the representation doesn't have to be faithful to give rise to a Chern class, but a faithful representation makes us often forget that the Lie group $G$ is something distinct from the set of matrices that represent it. The physicists only use compact gauge groups $G$, which all have faithful representations as complex matrices, and usually have an obvious choice of such a representation. The physicists are therefore just making their theory more concrete by working directly with matrices, forgetting abstract Lie groups.

Comment: @BenMcKay Could you leave a comment about the adjoint bundle? Mr Igor Belegradek said that it isn't right to take the adjoint bundle. However, in example 4.3.13 of this book https://books.google.se/books?id=l6F0DgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false the author is talking about the Pontryagin class of the adjoint bundle, the chern class of the complexified adjoint bundle, and the Chern class of the principal bundle.

Comment: @NewStudent: To convince yourself that you are using a wrong definition do a dimension count. The Chern class of the complexified adjoint bundle certainly make sense. Since $U(n)$ is a real Lie group of dimension $n^2$, the complexified adjoint rep acts on $\mathbb C^{n^2}$, so its Chern classes live in $H^*(BU(n^2))$. For a principal $U(n)$ bundle the Chern class lies in $H^*(BU(n))$. So unless $n=1$ they cannot possibly be equal by dimension reasons.

Comment: or rather since ad has a kernel I am one dimension off but it still fails.

Comment: I am also trying to read some characteristic classes... Do you wish to discuss on emails...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Hi could you give me your email address? I am willing to talk to you but since I have never been formally trained in mathematics, I am not sure if I will be helpful and can understand you.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Thank you for that comment.

Comment: @NewStudent You can contact me on praphullakowshik@gmail.com

Comment: Hi @PraphullaKoushik I sent you an email. Thank you.